# Como adicionar vários telefones ao mesmo formulário de forma dinâmica?

Tags: php, sql

Estou estudando `PHP` e `SQL` e estou construindo um sistema para que minha mãe consiga gerenciar melhor todos os clientes que utilizam o serviço de transporte que ela presta.

Construí uma página de registro simples com as informações necessárias, e gostaria de fazer uma atualização nela para adicionar telefones de contatos de forma dinâmica.

Por exemplo, ao menos um telefone de contato é obrigatório, portanto, um campo aparecerá por padrão, mas o meu problema está em adicionar mais telefones através do mesmo formulário, pois gostaria de colocar um botão de "+" para adicionar outro campo e registrar isso no banco de dados juntamente com os dados inseridos anteriormente, sem precisar criar uma página para cadastrar telefones a um usuário específico, um de cada vez.

Eu imagino que isso demande o uso de `JS`, porém eu realmente não faço de ideia de como começar a implementar na página de cadastro. Não consigo imaginar como ficaria o `SQL` e o `PHP`.

Para ter certeza de que eu não esqueci nenhuma parte do código, estarei disponibilizando todos os arquivos do projeto, está tudo muito simples, por conter somente o sistema de cadastro até o momento. 
[MEGA](https://mega.nz/#!9s0GWCSK!5K8T12qpYUJN7hsONsG3FM600eAMyycspCeizn6i7NI)

Enfim, desde já, deixo meu agradecimento aos que me ajudarem.

Comment: Poste seu código atual que está salvando apenas um telefone no caso.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Comment: Atualizei o post. Decidi adicionar todo o projeto para ter certeza de que eu não estou esquecendo nenhum trecho. Estou fazendo isso principalmente por ter me afastado do projeto por pouco mais de um mês.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom fiz um exemplo rápido (melhor que completar seu código e você não entender).

**1º** Tenho uma tabela `telefone` com `id`, `nome` e `telefone`:

```
--
-- Database: `sistema`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `sistema`;
USE `sistema`;

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `telefone`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `telefone` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `telefone`
--

INSERT INTO `telefone` (`id`, `nome`, `telefone`) VALUES
(1, 'Stack', '1111111111111'),
(2, 'Over', '22222222222222'),
(3, 'Flow', '333333333');
```

**2º** Monto minha página de cadastro (usei `jquery` e `bootstrap`):

```
<?php
require_once 'minpdo.php'; //importo minha biblioteca de crud
require_once 'telefone.php'; //php com definições do meu banco e tabela

$mnpdo = new MinPDO();
try {
    $telefones = $mnpdo->consult("telefone", "*"); // consulta todos telefones
} catch (MinPDOException $ex) { //caso haja erro
    echo <<<ERRO
    <div class="text-center text-danger">
    {$ex->getMessage()}
    </div>
ERRO;
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Cadastro dinâmico</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-hover" id="telefones">
            <tr class="text-primary">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <strong>Nome</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong>Telefone</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>

        <?php 
        if(!empty($telefones)) { // se tiver telefones
            for($i = 0; $i < count($telefones); $i ++) { //exibe todos
                echo <<<ITEM
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <p>{$telefones[$i]['nome']}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>{$telefones[$i]['telefone']}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
ITEM;
            }
        }
        ?>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr class="text-center">
                <td>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nome:</label>
                        <input name="nome" class="form-control" id="nome" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Telefone:</label>
                        <input name="telefone" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="telefone" type="tel" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label style="opacity: 0;">...</label>
                        <input class="btn btn-primary form-control envia" value="+" type="submit" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(function(){
            $(".envia").click(function() {
                if( $('#nome').val() != "" && $('#telefone').val() ) { //se ambos tiverem com conteudo
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST", //tipo de registro
                        url: "cadastra.php", //pagina de cadastro
                        data: { //envia nome e telefone
                            nome : $("#nome").val(),
                            telefone : $("#telefone").val()
                        } ,
                        success: function(retorno) {
                            if(retorno == "fail") {
                                //falha
                            } else {
                                $("table#telefones tr:last").after(retorno); //exibe novo registro
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

A parte mais importante aí é o `script`, note o uso do `Ajax`, é ele que permite fazer esse cadastro dinâmico, nele informo o método, a página onde irei tratar meus dados, os dados e também quando der sucesso etc.

**3º** Meu `INSERT` com a página **cadastra.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'minpdo.php';
require_once 'telefone.php';

$mnpdo = new MinPDO();
if(isset($_POST['nome']) and isset($_POST['telefone'])) {
    try { //tenta inserir e dar echo (retorno do ajax) de uma linha da tabela
        $mnpdo->insert("telefone",
            array("nome", "telefone"),
            array($_POST['nome'], $_POST['telefone']) );

        echo <<<ITEM
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <p>{$_POST['nome']}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>{$_POST['telefone']}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
ITEM;
    } catch (MinPDOException $ex) {
        echo "fail"; // falha do bd
    }
} else {
    echo "fail"; // não tem dados
}
```

Note que esse é a página que faz o `insert`, então é ela quem cito no `ajax`. Caso dê tudo certo ela retornará para o `ajax` o linha de tabela para meu novo registro, caso não, ela retorna uma mensagem `"fail"`

---

O exemplo pode ser baixado [nesse link do MEGA](https://mega.nz/#!gl4SGRrB!yb-h0GD44fXpOT2Bd3MKsOYu7AHiUcfkZL8lIIWogLc), para testar, rode o arquivo `sistema.sql` no seu gerenciador de dados, e entre no `index.php`. O arquivo `minpdo.php` é uma classe que fiz de `CRUD` para auxiliar meus projetos, caso tenho interesse [nesse link do GitHub](https://github.com/Leonardo-Souza/MinPDO) há o tutorial de como usa-la.

Comment: Na verdade o que eu estava tentando dizer, é que eu gostaria de adicionar mais campos para colocar números telefônicos, no mesmo formulário, ao pressionar um botão. Por exemplo:

Meu formulário é o seguinte:
(NOME) (SOBRENOME)
(TELEFONE) [ADICIONAR TELEFONE]

Ao pressionar o botão "Adicionar telefone", o formulário irá assumir a seguinte forma:
(NOME) (SOBRENOME)
(TELEFONE)(TELEFONE) [ADICIONAR TELEFONE]

Era isso que eu estava tentando dizer, para mim a explicação estava boa, mas acho que possa ter ficado meio confusa.

Comment: Ê particamente a mesmo cousa, so ocultar esse campo de colocar um nobo e colocar pra mostrar ele apenas quando o usuario apertar no botão

Comment: Certo, vou tentar. Desde já obrigado pela ajuda e pelo tempo.

Comment: Completei o exemplo fazendo com que ele faça isso que você quer e também tenha ação de apagar e editar. Download: https://mega.nz/#!NtQC2T6A!JAkc10JfrBbcA0HCNytn3hTvkfHgAxVBqCAeDZaHe8A